# Validator deposits in beacon api [Prysm]

Tags: validators, prysm, beacon

I am running a private network with Ethereum 2.0 (pos). Using Geth and Prysm. I sent a deposit to the  staking contract address an now, I'm querying the beacon node API at /eth/v1/beacon/states/head/validators. But I don't see my validator here even after 7-8 hours. Is this the correct approach, or have I overlooked something?

Also is there any way to reduce this time?

Is it the right way or am i missing something?

Appreciate your help